# Are there any Android phones which support extended APDUs?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I am developing an Android app which has function to read data from a smart card.
By default, NFC Controllers support APDU command with maximum transceive length is 261 bytes in single command. Because of large data need to be read on the card, the speed of reading is very slow.
Are there any Android phones which support extended APDUs allow to send more than 261 bytes in single APDU ?
Or are there any ways to modify the maximum transceive length by calling Android API to allow to do that?

I have found some topic:
[link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76598)

In which they increased the hard-coded value in the NativeNfcManager.java and rebuilt the NFCService (NfcNci.apk). But I am looking for a more simple solution for that.
Do you have any suggestions, please tell me?
Thanks a lot.