# Send more than 261 bytes to Java Card with Android NFC

Tags: android, nfc, javacard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I want to send an APDU with a length of 1699 bytes via NFC (class `IsoDep`) to a Java Card smartcard. I get the error

> java.io.IOException: Transceive length exceeds supported maximum

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S7.

I use extended-length in my applet on the card. I have verified that the card supports extended length. I tested this via pyapdutool by sending an APDU with 4000 bytes to the card.

I found that when I write this code, the result is `false`:

```
final Tag t = (Tag) tag;
myTag = IsoDep.get(t);
boolean result = myTag.isExtendedLengthApduSupported();
```

I have this in my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".test"
        android:label="@string/title_test"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

How can I send an APDU with 1699 bytes (or any length greater than 261 bytes) through Android NFC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173077/are-there-any-android-phones-which-support-extended-apdus

Comment: the topic is unsolved to my knowledge

Comment: It is not clear, whether the card supports such a length. Did you try it from a desktop PC and worked it there?

Comment: Even my laptop which sports an NFC chip doesn't support extended length. Unfortunately it's the same story all over again. First "normal" smart card readers didn't support Extended Length, then they did in an extremely buggy way, and nowadays there seem only minor issues left. I presume it will go the same way for NFC chips (although these are even cheaper, so it may take even more time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can't easily do that.

You already found out that `IsoDep` does not "support" extended-length APDUs on your device (i.e. `isoDep.isExtendedLengthApduSupported()` returns `false`). In fact this does **not** mean that you can't send extended-length APDUs through the `IsoDep` object. It actually only means that the `IsoDep` object won't properly split extended-length APDUs across more than two ISO-DEP blocks and consequently an APDU that is longer than 261 bytes will be assumed to exceed the transmit buffer size. You should still be able to send extended-length APDUs with sizes <= 261 bytes.

So `isoDep.isExtendedLengthApduSupported()` actually indicates if you can send more than 261 bytes in one ISO-DEP transceive.

What you could do to overcome this problem is to not use the `IsoDep` object at all and, instead, manually implement ISO-DEP (the ISO/IEC 14443-4 transmission protocol) on top of the `NfcA` object (if your card is based on NFC-A / ISO/IEC 14443 Type A) or the `NfcB` object (if your card is based on NFC-B / ISO/IEC 14443 Type B **and** if your device supports exchanging data over the `NfcB` object). You could then split your extended-length APDUs into ISO-DEP blocks that are small enough for the transceive buffer of the NFC controller (typically 253 bytes including the header bytes, excluding the CRC bytes). However, handling the ISO-DEP protocol yourself also means that you have to take care of proper ISO-DEP activation, of handling block numbering, block acknowledgements, timeouts, waiting-time extension, etc. Which is rather complicated, and particularly timeouts are not easy to observe due to the delays through the Android NFC stack.

Comment: I want to have key pair and certificate in my card. is it a pki card? does pki card have a certificate? Do you have a better suggestion for me?

Comment: @Fatemeh I'm not sure how that relates to extended-length APDU support.

Comment: Thank you for complete answer but I want to create a certificate in a java card with using android app. I create key pair in card and Issue a cert with using nfc and now I want to store cert in card. Do you have a better suggestion for me instead isodep class?

Comment: @Fatemeh You don't need extended length APDUs to write large amounts of data to a Java Card applet. Instead, you would implement your write (e.g. WRITE/UPDATE BINARY command) to transfer data in multiple smaller chunks.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I wrote my code according your explain but I get error again. I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395275/write-large-data-in-smart-card-via-nfc-in-android. can you help me?