# Read Large data from Smart card With Error tag was lost

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard

I want to Read/write large data in smart card via nfc in Android App.
according link [Send more than 261 bytes to Java Card with Android NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366099/send-more-than-261-bytes-to-java-card-with-android-nfc/40375229?noredirect=1#comment68024797_40375229)
 I can write  large apdu block by block.

but when I want to read large data I have problem:
I wrote this code for read large data in android app

```
  public  byte[] ReadCertificate(int keyindex)
{
    byte ReadCertAPDU[]=new byte[5];
    byte Read_Cert_CLA = AppletCLA;
    byte Read_Cert_INS = (byte)0x26;
    byte Read_Cert_P1 = (byte)0x00;
    byte Read_Cert_P2 = (byte)keyindex;
    byte Read_Cert_LE = (byte)0xFF;

    byte[] cert=new byte[2000];
    ReadCertAPDU[0] = Read_Cert_CLA;
    ReadCertAPDU[1] = Read_Cert_INS;
    ReadCertAPDU[2] = Read_Cert_P1;
    ReadCertAPDU[3] = Read_Cert_P2;
    ReadCertAPDU[4] = Read_Cert_LE;

    try {

        byte[] response = transceives(ReadCertAPDU);
        if(response==null)
            return null;

        else {
            if (response[0] == (byte) 0x61)
                response = GetResult2(LogStep, response);
            return response;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e( LogStep,e.getMessage()+" IOException on Sent Command: ");
    }
    return  null;

}
```

I get Error Tag was lost in exception in transceives() method.when I test it in pyapdu tool I don't have problem. and I get data + 61FF that I continue sending 00c00000ff and I get result. but in android app I have problem
in my applet I have method :

```
private void ReadCertificate(APDU apdu)
 {
     byte[] buffer=apdu.getBuffer();
     byte P2=buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2];

     Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(((byte[])CertificateArray[P2]),(short)0,Certificate, (short) 0,(short)Certificate.length);


    short toSend = (short) Certificate.length; 

    try {
        apdu.setOutgoing();
        apdu.setOutgoingLength(toSend);
        byte counter = 0;
        short senddate;
        while (toSend > 0) {
            if(toSend>255)
                senddate=(short)255;
            else
                senddate=toSend;
            apdu.sendBytesLong(Certificate, (short) (255 * counter), senddate);

            toSend = (short) (toSend - senddate);
            counter = (byte) (counter + 1);
        }
    } 
  catch (Exception e) {

    }
 }
```

Comment: You are aware that (byte)256 == 0, right? You can only send at most 255 bytes of data in one command APDU. This does not explain why you would get the exeeded length exception though (since you are not sending more than 261 bytes in total). You are still using `IsoDep` to transceive, right?

Comment: Excuse me..I can't understand. yes I use Isodep.but I generate a loop and send apdu block by block. in applet and by one bit lc I can send 256 byte. and I think ,It is not problem if I send lower than 261 .i send (5 + 255) I'm confused can you give me a sample code

Comment: I write myTag = IsoDep.get(t); one time in my class constructor and for each method in class I use my tag. I execute 5 method and I send apdu and get response.I don't have problem, but in method 6 I get this error .It is wrong?

Comment: The highes Lc value that you can use is 255 (all bits set to one in a 1-byte field). What is the value of `cert.length`?

Comment: Thank you for answer me. cert is a digital certificate . It's length is 1966 byte

Comment: Then I don't see why it would fail at exactly the 6th iteration (I assume by "method 6" you mean the 6th round of the while loop, right?

Comment: You do get the "Transceive length exceeds..." `IOException` and not some other `IOException`/`Exception` though?

Comment: no It is mean I use my tag in 6 methods in my class. I don't have problem for 5 methods (generate key.generate signature,....) and I use my tag. but im method 6 (write certificate) when I do one time while loop for second time I get error

Comment: yes I only get "Transceive length exceeds..." in my exception in method transceives().

Comment: I'm debugging it. let me test it again and after it write new result

Comment: Thank you Mr Michael. (byte)256 was wrong in write method and (byte)255 was correct as you said. but now when I want to read data ,I get error tag was lost.

Comment: Are you again trying to read chunks of more than 256 bytes?

Comment: Thanks in Advance,No as you see in applet code,i wrote 255 bytes

Comment: Since you expect data + a `61xx` response code I had the impression that you do try to send more than 256 bytes as response. Is that other reader that you use with pyapdutool one with a contact interface or a contactless one?

Comment: My card is doual interface. When i use pyapdu tool i insert it in a reader that it is connected pc with usb cable.is my applet code correct?total length is 1966 that i want to read. I wrote it in loop.and i expect 61xx in response to get all bytes

Comment: I use nfc when i want to read data(1966 bytes)from android app in my phone and use pyapdu tool when i wan to use cantact interface and usb reader(pc/sc reader)

Comment: You are running into the exact same problem that you had with your write method: You can't exchange extended length APDUs with an Android device. This **also applies** to response APDUs generated by the card. You have to exchange your data in smaller chunks instead. This also means that you have to send a command APDU for receiving each chunk. Just using `apdu.sendBytesLong()` in the JavaCard applet won't help you there Since this actually sends one large response APDU.

Comment: The reason why you see the data "automatically" split into multiple chunks (where you can retrieve each chunk with a GET RESPONSE APDU) is the *contact interface* which speaks a slightly different protocol than the NFC interface. This autmatic splitting won't happen over NFC and consequently your response data will be too long (i.e. all your `apdu.sendBytesLong()` will be assembled into one response APDU.)

Comment: Thank you,i let me edit my code and test it again